# Проблема потребления памяти в android api 26 и выше

Tags: android, память

При проверке приложения под Android, начиная с api 26, потребление памяти возрастает в разы. Из-за чего это может происходить? При просмотре в android studio в profiler (memory), показывается потребление памяти в пункте native аж 300 мб, но если api ниже 26, то native всего 13 мб.

Comment: библиотеки могут отличаться

Comment: действительно библиотеки отличаются, а именно (особо сильно) android.view.View и android.widget.ImageView. И если в этом причина, то как исправлять не понятно.

Comment: я думаю никак вы библиотеку не исправите, если это не сказывается на производительности